# Changing the content of jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I am developing mobile app using jquery mobile framework and I would like to change page content using javascript and ajax but I don't get the expected result.Could you help me please.
Here is the code :

connection.php

```php
<?php
    $dbhost="localhost";
    $dbuser="root";
    $dbpass="";
    $db="mobileapp";
    $conn=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die("Could not connect");
    mysql_select_db($db);
    ?>
```

index1.php

```php
<?php
    include 'connection.php';
    $fetch="SELECT * from users";
    /**
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    //while($person=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $person=mysql_fetch_array($result)
    echo json_encode($person);**/
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
      $row_array['username'] = $row['username'];
      $row_array['city'] = $row['city'];

      array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }

echo json_encode($return_arr);


    //}
?>
```

index.html

```html
<html> 
            <head> 
            <title>My Page</title> 
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-.0.1.min.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js">    </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="global.js">
            </script>

        </head> 
        <body> 

        <div data-role="page" id="page1">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Railway Station</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->


            <div data-role="content">
            <input type="button" value="Refresh" id="submit" data-icon="refresh" /></br>
            <ul data-role="listview" id="list"> </ul>
        <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                $(document).live('pageinit',function (event) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'index1.php',
                        data:"",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(rows) 
                            { 
                                for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) 
                                    { 
                                        var row = rows[i]; 
                                        var id = row[0]; 
                                        var name= row[1]; 
                                        var city= row[2];
                                        $('#list').append("<li>id:"+id+"Name:"+name+"City:"+city+"</li>");
                                    } 
                            };
                    });
                }); 
        </script>


        </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
                <h1>&copy;AmeyPat.All Rights Reserved.</h1>
            </div><!-- /footer -->




        </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Define the _expected result_? listview items with no styles?

Comment: Sorry Omar I don't understand your questions

Comment: "_but I don't get the expected result_" What is the problem? what are you getting? what do you expect to get? what do you want to achieve? :)

Comment: I would like to print on my browser all users registered in my local mysql database when I click to refresh button but when I click to refresh button I don't get any result.

Comment: Bind a click listener to button and rub same code you have in pageinit. Btw, you're using an outdated version of JQM, use latest version 1.4 with jQuery 1.9 at least.

Comment: I changed Jquery Mobile version by including the fallowing lines but it does not work                                                               <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

Comment: Have you done the following inside `pageinit` or `pagecreate`? `$("#btn_ID").on("click", function () { ajax call code });`.